# ScriptIntrinsicBlur on Bitmap API<14

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bitmap, android-api-levels

I need to put blurred background image on Navigation header view in Android API<14. I read lot of documentation on ScriptIntrinsicBlur but he has been added on API<17.

I know 
`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND)` exist but it seems to be use on windows, not on Bitmap Image.

Do you know how transform my Bitmap image in blurred Bitmap or Drawable on API<14 ?

Thanks !

**EDIT :**

**- Step 1:** Add to build.gradle(Module: app):

```
`Android{
    [...]
    dependencies{
        [...]
        renderscriptTargetApi 14
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
}`
```

**- Step 2** import android.support.v8.renderscript.*;

It Work ! ScriptIntrinsicBlur is now ready to use. Thanks to Nikola Despotoski For his help.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  In your code sample, the `\`Android` should be `android` , and `dependencies` should be `defaultConfig`, then it works as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ScriptIntrinsicBlur` from the [v8 support library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v8/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBlur.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code below. it works api level below 16

http://incubator.quasimondo.com/processing/stackblur.pde
https://github.com/wingjay/BlurImageView/blob/master/blurimageviewlib/src/main/java/com/wingjay/blurimageviewlib/FastBlurUtil.java